# Accordion save last state on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I'm building a accordion menu and I'm trying to keep the last active state of the accordion on page reload. I've tried javascript (see below) but it doesn't seem to work.

[See Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXeGyO)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.b-accordion').accordion({
header: '.b-accordion__cell',
collapsible: true,
activate: function(e, ui) {
localStorage.setItem('accordion-active', $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ));
},
active: +localStorage.getItem('accordion-active')
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to record state between page reloads (much simpler than `localStorage`) is to take advantage of the URI `hash` fragment.

The `<a>` anchor element is block level in `HTML5`, so you could, for example, surround each of your `<li>` list items, like this:

```
<a href="#info"><li class="b-accordion__cell">[CODE HERE]</li></a>
<a href="#method"><li class="b-accordion__cell">[CODE HERE]</li></a>
<a href="#material"><li class="b-accordion__cell">[CODE HERE]</li></a>
<a href="#medium"><li class="b-accordion__cell">[CODE HERE]</li></a>
```

When the page reloads, the `hash` fragment of the URI will straightforwardly indicate which part of the accordion needs to be expanded.